# Como unir dos formularios WinForms a una sola ventana en tiempo de ejecucion

Tags: c#, windows-forms, interfaz-gráfica

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de mostrar por completo un formulario pero sea en la misma ventana sin abrir una nueva, he usado  MDI el problema que un ListView oculta el formulario hijo. Al final la ventana esta llena de labels, botones,ListViews  quisiera saber si existe otra alternativa o lo hecho con MDI tiene solución adjunto una captura para que se comprenda el comportamiento de lo que explico, mi unico objetivo es que no se habran una ventana por cada formulario sino una sola ventana por todos los formularios de mi proyecto cuando se ejecuta el proyecto ...Gracias [image: La parte de negro es un label, y oculta el formulario.]

Comment: Pruena usando TABs

Answer (score 0):

Agrega un control tipo contenedor (nombre = micontenedor) dentro del formulario.

```
FrmHijo frmHijo = new FrmHijo();

frmHijo.AutoScroll = true;
frmHijo.TopLevel = false;

micontenedor.Controls.Add(frmHijo);

frmHijo.Show();
```